# Regex to replace between starting curly bracket { and colon :

Tags: c#, regex

I wanted to replace a part of string between curly bracket and colon. Suppose I have a string like :

`{Name: {\"before\":'Aj', \"after\":'Ajay'} },`

So now I want to replace the part of string `{Name:` with `{"Name":`.

I tried doing `Regex.Replace(rectifyAfter, @"/{([^\s].+?)(\s|$):", "{\"$1\":")`. But it doesn't do the replace.

Can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: Modifying JSON this way is the job for a parser.  Personally, I would try to fix the source data so that you don't need to do this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Actually the souce data is coming from the DB which got stored due to wrong code in first place. I have fixed it now. But for the old data I need to replace using regex.

Comment: Are the keys which have the problem all unique, and all broken in the same way?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, the keys are different but all are broken is same way.

Comment: Something wrong with just doing find `Name:` and replace `"Name:"` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry I didn't make myself clear. The keys are different but all are broken is same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should do the trick:

```
(?:\{)(?<Property>[a-z0-9]+)(?:\:)
```

What it does:

`(?:\{)` - matches but doesn't capture the opening curly bracket

`(?<Property>[a-z0-9]+)` - captures the name of the property in a capturing group named `Property`

`(?:\:)` - again, matches but doesn't capture the `:` after the property

So, basically, what you want to do is match the pattern `{Name:` but have it replaced with `{"` + *value of `Property` group* + `:`.

And below is the code to do the replacement:

```
string pattern = @"(?:\{)(?<Property>[a-z0-9]+)(?:\:)";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string targetString = @"{Name: {\""before\"":'Aj', \""after\"":'Ajay'} },";
string replacement = @"{""${Property}"":";
return regex.Replace(targetString, replacement);
```

`${Property}` is the name of the capturing group and it will hold the name of your property.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much. You saved my time. :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you'd need regex for this. Just use a simple `.Replace`

```
string json = "" //Whatever your JSON string is.
json = json.Replace("{Name:", "{\"Name\":");
```